# Does debugging angular app in localhost potentially makes it behave differently?

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, angular7

We have this Angular 7 app with following packages and more,

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
```

**Problem:**

```
Browser        Environment        Works
Edge           Live(IIS)           No
Edge           UAT(IIS)            No
Edge           Localhost           Yes
Chrome\FF      Live(IIS)           Yes
Chrome\FF      UAT(IIS)            Yes
Chrome\FF      Localhost           Yes
```

By not working I mean it's not loading anything other then header and there are no errors in console log. Being new to angular 7, I have no idea where to start from ?

**Update**

Based on useful suggestions in comment, I did ng serve --aot then error I was getting...

> ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(60,32): Error during template compile
>   of 'AppModule'   Function calls are not supported in decorators but
>   'BusyConfig' was called.

for code block,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        .. some stuff
        BusyModule.forRoot(new BusyConfig({
          template: '<div class="my-loader"></div>'
        })),
        ... so on ...
```

Then I added a following function to end of app.module file,

```
export function busyConfigFactory() {
    return new BusyConfig({
        template: '<div class="my-loader"></div>'
    });
}
```

and added it in providers as,

```
{ provide: BusyConfig, useFactory: busyConfigFactory }
```

and commented out BusyModule.forRoot(new BusyConfig... block, but now I am getting this error,

> ERROR in : Can't bind to 'ngBusy' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ng-container'.
>   1. If 'ngBusy' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
>   2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("][ngBusy]="busy">
>       
>           Create Ne")

Comment: Did you check `polyfills.ts` file? You may need to enable some of the polyfills. Also, can you share some code and maybe screenshot of your app in the browser?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner sorry for asking question over question but why would it work in localhost if it's related to polyfills issue ? Does debugging app in localhost potentially makes angular app behave differently ?

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be related to AOT(ahead-of-time) and JIT (just-in-time) compiler. When you `serve` your app in your localhost, the default compiler is `JIT`. However, when you run `ng build` and deploy it to some server, angular uses `AOT` compiler. So, `JIT` may contain some code which makes it work in your `localhost`

Comment: You can test this by running `ng serve --aot` in your localhost.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner ta for your useful suggestions, I have reached this stage now - https://prnt.sc/mk13lr, basically it failed and upon further changes it still fails, not sure if it's relevant at all or just a distractor

Comment: It is relevant, meaning that your application does not work with `AOT` compiler. Can you add those log to your question as the links may die in the future? We can work from there.

Comment: I'm not sure how you set up `BusyModule` `ngBusy` directive may be missing.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I tried to remove BusyModule completely and it works with ng serve but gives more errors with ng serve -aot, but it seems like a endless cycle, is there any other way possible for me to at least get a error from staging\production environment, as they are not working but there isn't any error at all in browser

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with safe websites or a setting in edge ? which it ignores for localhost but gets tough on proper urls

Comment: According to your code, it seems that you want to use angular Singleton services, I suggest you check [this article](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) to use forRoot function.